# Deleting some rows in a MySQL table

Tags: python, mysql

I have a MySQL db which includes 2 interlinked tables called 'files' and 'path'. The 'files' table has several hundred rows and I would like to delete rows if the corresponding file has been deleted from the file system, ie 90+%.

I can list the files which are no longer present with the following Python code:

```
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors
import os.path

con = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
      db='MyVideos116',
      user='kodi',
      password='****',
      charset='utf8mb4',
      cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

with con:  
  cur = con.cursor()
  cur.execute("SELECT f.*, p.* FROM files f INNER JOIN path p ON f.idPath = p.idPath")
  rows = cur.fetchall()

  for row in rows:
     fileExists = os.path.isfile(row["strPath"] + row["strFilename"])
     if not fileExists:
        print(row["idFile"], row["strPath"], row["strFilename"])
```

I have tried to use the os.path.isfile() phrase as part in a WHERE clause such as:

```
cur.execute("SELECT f.*, p.* FROM files f INNER JOIN path p ON p.idPath = f.idPath WHERE os.path.isfile(p.strPath+f.strFilename")
```

but that does not seem to be permissible. In pseudo code what I want to do is:

```
for each row in files table
   if file does not exist then
      delete row
   end if
next row
```

Looks pretty simple, how do I do it?

Comment: Why not perform the delete in the `if not fileExists:` block?

Comment: You cannot execute python code as part of your mysql code. As @IainShelvington has pointed out: execute a delete statement from the `if not fileExists:` block by using the file name or path as a string parameter.